# Getting a Java program to select a random word from an array and then print the index above the characters

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am attempting to create a word unscramble game program. The program selects a random word from a list of words in a text file and puts them in an array. It then prints out the word with the index numbers above it. I can't seem to get the indexes to match up to the selected words length. It keeps printing out every index in the text file. The output is always 10 index numbers with a shorter word under it. How do I get the extra indexes to not print?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Midterm { // class header

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Method header

        String[] words = readArray("words.txt");
        /*
         * Picks a random word from the array built from words.txt file. Prints
         * index with word beneath it.
         */
        int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 11);

        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j = j + 1) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
        char[] charArray = words[randNum].toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }


    }

    // end main


    public static String[] readArray(String file) {
        // Step 1:
        // Count how many lines are in the file
        // Step 2:
        // Create the array and copy the elements into it

        // Step 1:
        int ctr = 0;
        try {
            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
                ctr = ctr + 1;
                s1.nextLine();
            }
            String[] words = new String[ctr];

            // Step 2:
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
            for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i = i + 1) {
                words[i] = s2.next();

            }
            return words;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loop is 0 -> words array length, if you want to print the indexes of the letters in the word itself, then your for loop should be like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < words[randNum].length(); j++)
    System.out.print(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Choose the `randNum` random number between 0 to words.length - 1, then you can access the word with `words[randNum]`.

Simplified Version :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Method header

    String[] words = readArray("words.txt");
    /*
     * Picks a random word from the array built from words.txt file. Prints
     * index with word beneath it.
     */

    //Choose random number between 0 to words.length - 1
    int randNum = new Random().nextInt(words.length);

    for (int j = 0; j < words[randNum].length(); j = j + 1) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println(words[randNum]);
}
```